# How to get google analytics data from php-curl not using sdk's?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, php-curl

I am going through google analytics API documents there I can only see how to get analytics data using SDK but I want get it through `curl POST` or `GET` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using curl and php I beleave you can still us the Google api php client library.  However as you said you dont want to use the client library the following should help you retrieve Google analytics data.

The endpoint is

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
```

Make sure you send an authorization header with a valid bearer token.

You can see all the json post boys in the sample page [samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples)

```
{
  "reportRequests":[
  {
    "viewId":"XXXX",
    "dateRanges":[
      {
        "startDate":"2015-06-15",
        "endDate":"2015-06-30"
      }],
    "metrics":[
      {
        "expression":"ga:sessions"
      }],
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "name":"ga:browser"
      }]
    }]
}
```

The google analytics reporting api v4 does not support get requests only post.

Comment: i am getting 401 error " "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }"

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postval));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: API KEY';

Comment: you didnt add the authorization header with your access token.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Comment: Is there still a way to access this information using GA4 and a propertyId?

Comment: GA4 doesn't have property id's they have measurement Id.

Comment: That's not true you can view it under property/settings regardless though is there a way to access analytic information using an HTTP request and a bearer api key?

Comment: okay you win it says property id,  I need to bring that up with the team.  Beyond that i think you should check the docs https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport

Comment: that looked promising, but I keep getting the error: API keys are not supported by this API. Am I correct in assuming they have done away with API keys for analytics in favor of open auth?

Comment: Api keys are only used to access public data, you need permission of the owner of the account to access the data you need to request authorization.   If you need a php sample let me know i should have one laying around.